# taking price from object arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, parameters

How can I create an array (not arraylist) which holds customers' ids?

For example. When the first customer registered, it's id is 01, then second registered its id 02.

Secondly is this true to initialize an array:

```
private ArrayList<Product> products;
products = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays need to be given a size when created. ArrayList would be a better option for an ongoing Array increasing in size. When initializing an ArrayList you have to declare what type of objects the ArrayList is going to hold.

```
private ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

The question has been edited and is now initialized correctly, it was missing object declaration previously.